# Unable to set the value to a Label during the TextChanged event using ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code that is supposed to set the error label to an error message if some condition isn't met during the `TextChanged` event

Here is the aspx:

The error message `Label`

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" />
```

The actual `TextBox` that calls the `TextChanged` event

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel24" runat="server" class="inline">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label29" runat="server" Text="*" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddSomeList" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel25" runat="server" class="inline">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSomeValue" runat="server" Text="Some Text"></asp:Label>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddSomeValue" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="someimage" TabIndex="-1" runat="server"
                    ID="ImageButton16" CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="Navigate('sometext');return false;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel26" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox CssClass="textboxefile" runat="server" ID="txtSomeValue"
                            MaxLength="7" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtSomeValue_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator SetFocusOnError="true" Enabled="false" ID="rfv_SomeValue"
                            runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtSomeValue" ErrorMessage="* Required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                    </ContentTemplate>

                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddSomeValue" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the codebehind

```
    protected void txtSomeValue_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtSomeValue.Text.Trim() != "" && !ValidateValue(txtSomeValue.Text))
        {

                    lblMessage.Text = "Wrong Value"         
        }
    }
```

When I put a breakpoint in the `TextChanged` event, that breakpoint actually gets hit, the event does get fired. But the `Label` doesn't get set, it stays blank.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Your quotes are mismatched: `lblMessage.Text = "Wrong Value'` If you're starting with double quotes, you must end with double quotes. You also missed a semicolon in that line. Were these typos made while transferring your code to StackOverflow?

Comment: try putting your label in the same content template

Comment: As noted by Donny in above comment, the label you attempting to change has to be in the update panel - not outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments gave me the right answer, I had to include the label into an UpdatePanel

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" class="col-md-12 alignCenter">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblMessage" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: It would be nice of you to let the person who have you the hint know so that they write the answer and you accept it. This way someone is credited for helping.